# Laravel on delete objects call model event - deleted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, model, relational-database

Im trying to call model event - deleted. When Im deleting a video, I also want delete all comments which are associated with video, that is working fine. But I have also feeds table and when Im deleting video I want also delete all comments and comments feeds. Now when Im deleting video, I delete - video, video comments, video feed, but I need delete also video comment feeds.

The question is how I can make it possible to delete also comments feeds when Im deleting video?
Check VideoController.php destroy function

Video.php - Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Video extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'videos';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use Sluggable, RecordsFeed;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    public function sluggable()
    {
      return [
          'slug' => [
              'source' => 'title'
          ]
        ];
    }

    public function comments()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\VideoComment', 'videoid', 'id');
    }

    public function member()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'userid', 'member_id');
    }

}
```

VideoComments.php - Model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VideoComment extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'videos_comments';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
      'text', 'userid', 'date'
    ];
    use RecordsFeed;

    public function videos() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Video', 'id', 'videoid');
    }
    public function member() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Member', 'userid', 'member_id');
    }
}
```

RecordsFeed.php

```
    <?php

namespace App;
use App\Libraries\Portal;

trait RecordsFeed
{

    protected static function bootRecordsFeed() {

        static::created(function($model) {
            $model->recordFeed('created');
        });

        static::deleted(function($model) {
            $model->deleteFeed('deleted');
        });

    }

    public function feeds() {
        return $this->morphMany( Feed::class, 'feedable' );
    }

    protected function recordFeed($event) {
        $this->feeds()->create([
            'user_id' => (new Portal)->getMemberID(),
            'type' => $event.'_'.strtolower(class_basename($this))
        ]);
    }

    protected function deleteFeed($event) {
        $this->feeds()->delete();
    }

}
```

VideoController.php destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $video = Video::findOrFail($id);
    $video->comments()->delete();
    $video->delete();

    Session::flash('success', 'Video deleted');
    return redirect()->route('video.index');
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code here. not on github and not on images

Comment: *The question is how I can make it possible to delete also comments feeds when Im deleting video?* By programming it. Please post relevant code, what went wrong, what you tried and what you expect.

Comment: Post updated guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you not use on delete cascade at the creation of your table ?

In your migration, when you create your foreign key, just specify the on delete action like this :

```
$table->foreign('your_key')->references('id')->on('your_table')->onDelete('cascade');
```

It will automatically delete rows which are associated to the parent object.

You can find more details in Laravel documentation just [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: Ty, forgot about that. Excelent.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have do anything code, you can set in database and set delete on cascade with relationshiop.